# Sequential stored procedure with User Input

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a web app that takes user input and generates an image from user input. Those images should be generated in a sequence and will need to reset everyday.

I'm trying to at least store the sequence values, the sequence and the date into a database, but it will not update.

So far, my database will not update, my code works, but is not performing correctly. I'm not sure where my problem lies. I found similar help online, but they did not seem to work.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE barcode_insert(
    @Seq_Num int,
    @date datetime,
    @ImageName varchar
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE ImageInfoTable
    SET imagedate = @date,ImageNum = @Seq_Num
    WHERE image_name = @ImageName
END

RETURN @Seq_Num
```

C# Code

```
protected void gen_barcode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

    string date_picker = datepicker.Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "barcode_insert"

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seq_Num", amount.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date_picker);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", CheckBox.Checked);

    if (CheckBox_Code.Checked)
    {
          //generate image code
    }

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am sure that they are just typo's but your stored procedure looks to have a couple issues: =+ is not an operator and you need a comma after the first column in the SET statement. I think you meant this:  `SET imagedate = @date,
ImageNum = @Seq_Num` ?

Comment: They were, I apologize, I edited the Stored Procedure Code in the question

Comment: The other issue that I see is that you are using the datepicker control in the parameter instead of the datepicker controls value. Should be date_picker.

Comment: Check your sample C# code to make sure it is the same as your real code. There are obvious and not-so-obvious errors in it.

Comment: What about `"@ImageName", CheckBox.Checked`? Are your image names just `true/false`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the types of your parameters explicitly.

```
protected void gen_barcode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date_picker = datepicker.Value;
    int intAmount; // get the int value for the amount here...
    String imgName; // get the image name here...
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "barcode_insert"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Seq_Num", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageName" , SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Seq_Num"].Value = intAmount;
    cmd.Parameters["@date"].Value = date_picker;
    cmd.Parameters["@ImageName"].Value = imgName;

    if (CheckBox_Code.Checked)
    {
          //put this somewhere else since it isn't related in function
    }

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes just like @AlexKudryashev stated there were errors in my initial code, I edited it, while the code works, it's not updating the table in the Database.

Comment: does the stored procedure update the data directly from SQL management studio?

Comment: yes it does, the number entered is not updated in the sequence, I applied the current date to the column in the database, when running my app, it changes to a date back to 2008

Comment: The stored procedure executes, but the date is not updated to the expected value when running from c# code?

Comment: that is correct as well as the number entered is not updated at all

Comment: Try setting the parameter types explicitly.  Also make sure that you are passing the correct type into the parameter.  I have update my answer.